# Compiling SWIG java library with mingw

Tags: java, c++, mingw, swig

I've got a Java project which depends on a native library. I'm using SWIG to build the native library, which works fine on *nix systems. I'm trying to get it to compile now on Windows using the mingw 64 bit toolchain and SWIG. It will compile and I can get the jnilib packaged appropriately (i.e. the same way as I'm doing it on other platforms) but when I try to load the library in the Java code I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: ... .jnilib: Can't find dependent libraries
```

and then it has the trace on the java side. Clearly I'm not linking something properly but I'm not sure what. Here's the relevant part of my compile commands:

```
swig -java -package cStopPow -c++ StopPow.i

x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -I"C:/Progra~1/Java/jdk1.7.0_25/include/" -I"C:/Progra~1/Java/jdk1.7.0_25/include/win32/" -std=c+
+11 -O3 -I"C:/MinGW/include/boost/math/" -c ../src/StopPow.cpp ../src/StopPow_SRIM.cpp ../src/StopPow_LP.cpp ../src/Stop
Pow_BetheBloch.cpp ../src/StopPow_AZ.cpp ../src/PlotGen.cpp ../src/AtomicData.cpp StopPow_wrap.cxx

x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -shared -lmingw32 -mconsole StopPow_wrap.o StopPow.o StopPow_SRIM.o StopPow_LP.o StopPow_BetheBlo
ch.o StopPow_AZ.o PlotGen.o AtomicData.o -o libcStopPow.jnilib
```

Answer (score 0):

Why the output is libcStopPow.jnilib? I think it must a dll file

I use SWIG 2.0.10, Oracle JDK 1.7.0_40 and mingw 64 from http://nuwen.net/ with the Examples\java\simple. I do the following in cmd (I set JAVA_HOME correctly)
swig -java -c++ example.i
g++ -Wall -Wl,--kill-at -I "%JAVA_HOME%/include" -I "%JAVA_HOME%/include/win32" -shared -s -o example.dll *.c *.cxx
java -cp . runme

It works as expected